# Selecting columns by character using get(), .data[[]]], and !! in dplyr

Tags: dplyr, evaluation

I have a frequent operation that I'd like to write a function to do in dplyr. I'd like to be able to concisely say "in this dataset, if variable a equals value b, change variable c to value d". I'd like to be able to pass in different variable names "a" and "b" in different contexts. There seem to be three methods people employ to use character strings as column arguments in dplyr:

1. Using !!, as in `key_variable = "x"; dataset = dataset %>% filter(!!key_variable == 3)`
2. Using .data[[]], as in `key_variable = "x"; dataset = dataset %>% filter(.data[[key_variable]] == 3)`
3. Using get() as in `key_variable = "x"; dataset = dataset %>% filter(get(key_variable) == 3)`

However, each of these seems to work in some cases and not others. Can anyone explain why? An example illustrating the point is below.

```
riib = function(dataset, selectvar) {

    selectname=deparse(substitute(selectvar))
    print(replacename)
    print(selectname)
    print(equalval)

    print("Selecting")
    #When selecting, !! works, .data[[]] works, get() doesn't (throws an error)
    print(dataset %>% select(!!selectname))
    print(dataset %>% select(.data[[selectname]]))
    # print(dataset %>% select(get(selectname)))

    print("Filtering")
    #When filtering !!selectname doesn't work (returns no rows), .data[[]] does, get() does
    print(dataset %>% filter(!!selectname == 3))
    print(dataset %>% filter(.data[[selectname]] == 3))
    print(dataset %>% filter(get(selectname) == 3))

    print("Mutating")
    #When mutating, !! works, .data[[]] doesn't and get() doesn't (latter two throw an error)
    print(dataset %>% mutate(!!selectname := 3))
    # print(dataset %>% mutate(.data[[selectname]] := 3))
    # print(dataset %>% mutate(get(selectname) := 3))
    print(dataset)
}

bob=tibble(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4))
bob
riib(bob,y)
```

To me it seems like there should be one syntax that tells dplyr "treat this character expression as a column name". What am I missing about how these three methods work?

Comment: By the way, UQ(sym(selectname)) seems to work in all cases. Still not sure what is different about each of the others.

Comment: Oh, also, ?dplyr_data_masking says to use "embracing", but when I try "embracing" R tells me that I have an unexpected equals sign: `riib4 = function(dataset, selectvar, selectval, replacevar, replaceval){
 dataset = dataset %>% mutate({{ selectvar }} = 5)
}`